# importing an array from a .dat file in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a .dat file which contains about 1000 lines each line contains

`letter int int int int boolean`
and i am trying to read it in so each line is a new row on my array.
currently I have `np.genfromtxt('myfile.dat')` which gives me

```
nan 23. 34. 23. 55. 1.
```

this is almost right but that `nan` should be the letter 't' any idea how I get to read in the correct letter? And also how do I get rid of the . after each number?
cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is defining a new `dtype`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

desc = np.dtype([('letter', 'S1'), ('v1', float), ('v2', float),
                 ('v3', float), ('v4', float)])
```

and use in `genfromtext`:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(fobj, dtype=desc)
```

This file content:

```
x 23. 34. 23. 55. 1.
y 23. 34. 23. 55. 1.
```

would give you this `data`:

```
array([(b'x', 23.0, 34.0, 23.0, 55.0), (b'y', 23.0, 34.0, 23.0, 55.0)], 
      dtype=[('letter', 'S1'), ('v1', '<f8'), ('v2', '<f8'), ('v3', '<f8'), ('v4', '<f8')])
```

This is an [record array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html#numpy.recarray). You can access one line:

```
>>> data[0]
(b'x', 23.0, 34.0, 23.0, 55.0)
```

or one column:

```
>>> data['letter']
    array([b'x', b'y'], 
          dtype='|S1')
```

or one entry:

```
>>> data[0][1]
23.0
>>> data['v1'][1]
23.0
```

Comment: This is working, but the file contains 2000 lines and when you get the shape I get (2000l,) this doesn't seem right isn't there might to be another number in there? cheers

Comment: shape (2001,) or (20001,) ?

Comment: Try `dtype=None`.  Either way the result will be a 1d structured array, one record per line.

Comment: Mike it gives (2000L), as in the letter, not sure what that means. dtype=None doesn't work.

Comment: 2000L  is a long integer. Northing to worried about. Looks you are on Windows using Python 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. 1 last thing, is there a way to just get say v1 for the 3rd element of the array? I was thinking v1.data[2], but this doesn't work

Comment: Try `data['v1'][2]`. This gives the entry for the third row in column `v1`. It is th same as `datat[2]['v1']`.